# A quick question on in logs

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I was solving indefinite integrals

$$\int_0^22^x x \,dx$$

I use ILATE as a clue to consider the first function and second function.
$2^x$ is a algebraic function or logarithmic function?

Comment: It is an exponential function? $2^x=e^{x\ln 2}.$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+2+x+*2%5Ex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For:
 $$\int\limits_{0}^{2} x\cdot 2^x\:dx$$ 
Take $2^x =t$, then we get $2^x \cdot \ln(2) \cdot dx=dt$, and, $x=\log_2(t)$. Thus:
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{2} x \cdot 2^x\:dx&=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\int\limits_{1}^{4}\log_2(t)\: dt \\
&=\frac{1}{(\ln(2))^2}\int\limits_{1}^{4}\ln(t) \: dt
\end{align}

Now, I leave it for you. Use by parts (Hint: $\ln(2)= 1\cdot\ln(2)$).